# get springboot application.properties env variables into config class

Tags: spring-boot-test

I am struggling to create a `config` class that holds final strings of configuration properties that I use elsewhere. I don't want to use the `Environment`. So I have some code

```
@Autowire
Environment env;

return this.webClient.get()
  .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(env.getProperty("endpoint")).build())
  .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
  .exchangeToFlux(e -> e.bodyToFlux(Event.class));
```

That's actually working fine, but I want to get my config together in a separate class, out of the environment. Like:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MyConfig {

  @Value("${endpoint}")
  public static final String URI = "";

  @Bean
  public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyConfigInDev() {
    return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
  }
}
```

In my springboot project when I change from `env` to use the `MyConfig` variable:

```
return this.webClient.get()
  .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(MyConfig.URI).build())
  .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
  .exchangeToFlux(e -> e.bodyToFlux(Event.class));
```

When I get a unit test going that's going to run the call to the `URI` config from the `MsgConfig` class it's always null. How can I get the thing to populate?

**UPDATE**

It looked as if removing the `static` from

```
public static final String URI = "";
```

and `@Autowire` the `MyConfig` class into the other class was going to work, and indeed sometimes it does, but this appears to cause a race condition whether the URI is set or not...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a configuration properties class, as described in the [Spring Boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties).

First, create a class to hold the configuration properties:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("endpoint")
public class EndpointProperties {

    private final URI uri;

    public MyProperties(URI uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

    public URI getUri() {
        return this.uri;
    }
}
```

Then enable the `EndpointProperties` using one of the techniques [described in the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.typesafe-configuration-properties.enabling-annotated-types).

You can then inject this into the class that needs the properties:

```
@Autowired EndpointProperties endpoint;

return this.webClient.get()
  .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(endpoint.getUri()).build())
  .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
  .exchangeToFlux(e -> e.bodyToFlux(Event.class));
```

In a Spring Boot `application.yml` file, you'd set the property value like this:

```
endpoint: 
  uri: https://example.com/api/
```